# Filtering a scala string sequence based on a list of strings

Tags: string, scala, filter, delimiter, collect

I have a Scala sequence which is of format `("Apple-fruit", "Banana-fruittoo", "Chocolate-notafruit")` and I have another Scala list of format `("Apple", "Banana")`

I want to filter my first sequence based on second list so that my final output is `("Apple-fruit", "Banana-fruittoo")`. Could anyone help me with this filter function?

Answer (score 6):

```
Seq("Apple-fruit", "Banana-fruittoo", "Chocolate-notafruit")
  .filter(x => Seq("Apple", "Banana").exists(y => x.contains(y)))
// Seq("Apple-fruit", "Banana-fruittoo")
```

For each item (x) of the seq to filter, we check if at least one element (y) of the filtering seq exists such as x contains y.

Comment: This works perfectly fine if the string cases are an exact match. 

It will fail with `val filteringSeq = Seq("apple", "banana")`

Comment: @RobertUdah I don't see this as a requirement in the question. In this case you could do: `seqToFilter.filter(x => filteringSeq.exists(y => x.toLowerCase.contains(y.toLowerCase)))`

Answer (score 0):

***Try this:***

```
x.filter(x=>y.contains(x.split("-")(0)))
```

for

```
val x = List("Apple-fruit", "Banana-fruittoo", "Chocolate-notafruit")
val y = List("Apple", "Banana")
```

### In Scala REPL:

```
scala> x.filter(x=>y.contains(x.split("-")(0)))
res130: List[String] = List(Apple-fruit, Banana-fruittoo)

scala>
```